# ClickOnce Application try to find an application manifest in a wrong location (strange parameters)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, clickonce

This is my third post on ClickOnce, but each of them has its own subject so I hope nobody minds this. I'm urgently migrating the existing app to the new server. I publish a ClickOnce application to a server (online usage only, not for install), and if I try to execute it via web browsers, I get a message box saying "Cannot continue. The Application is improperly formatted. Contact the application vendor for assistance.", the detail log of which includes below; (I masked some strings in the URL by ***, as it was private information)

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows : 5.1.2600.196608 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime : 4.0.30319.1
System.Deployment.dll : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
clr.dll : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
dfdll.dll : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
dfshim.dll : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCES
Deployment url: http://**.**.***.173:10080/*****/ClickOnce/*********.application?comid=*****&userjpname=************&userfullname=************&canregist=True&canmanage=True&systemid=0

ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of http://**.**.***.173:10080/*****/ClickOnce/*********.application?comid=*****&userjpname=************&userfullname=************&canregist=True&canmanage=True&systemid=0 resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
+ Exception reading manifest from http://**.**.***.173:10080/*****/ClickOnce/*********.application?comid=*****&userjpname=************&userfullname=************&canregist=True&canmanage=True&systemid=0: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
+ Manifest XML signature is not valid.
+ The digital signature of the object did not verify.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
* [2012/07/24 13:16:39] : Activation of http://**.**.***.173:10080/*****/ClickOnce/*********.application?comid=*****&userjpname=************&userfullname=************&canregist=True&canmanage=True&systemid=0 has started.

ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [2012/07/24 13:16:39] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
- Exception reading manifest from http://**.**.***.173:10080/*****/ClickOnce/*********.application?comid=*****&userjpname=************&userfullname=************&canregist=True&canmanage=True&systemid=0: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
- Source: System.Deployment
- Stack trace:
at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
--- Inner Exception ---
System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (SignatureValidation)
- Manifest XML signature is not valid.
- Source: System.Deployment
- Stack trace:
at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSignature(Stream s)
at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
--- Inner Exception ---
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
- The digital signature of the object did not verify.

- Source: System.Deployment
- Stack trace:
at System.Deployment.Internal.CodeSigning.SignedCmiManifest.Verify(CmiManifestVerifyFlags verifyFlags)
at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSignature(Stream s)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
No transaction information is available.
```

My server address is `http://**.**.***.173:10080`, and a clickonce app is published in `http://**.**.***.173:10080/*****/ClickOnce` folder.

I assume it tried to find an application manifest file (.manifest) with these several weird parameters (or query strings?) such as comid, userjpname, userfullname, canregist, canmanage, True and systemid, and thus it returned an error.

In my deployment manifest file, the location of the application manifest file is specified as below. No idea where these parameters came from.

```
<dependentAssembly 
    dependencyType="install"  
    codebase="MYAPPNAME_9_9_9_99\MYAPPNAME.exe.manifest"
    size="8532">
<assemblyIdentity
    name="MYAPPNAME.exe"
    version="1.0.1.43"
    publicKeyToken="*************"
    language="neutral"
    processorArchitecture="msil"
    type="win32" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to sign the application  and deployment manifests again?

Reading you description again, I'm a bit confused.

First you create an application manifest.

Then you sign it.

Then you create a deployment manifest and explicitly point it to your application manifest.

Then you sign this, too.

(btw: you have to do the signing part every time you change something.)